# Como enviar correos desde codeigniter con phpmailer?

Tags: php, javascript, bootstrap, codeigniter, phpmailer

Hola buenos dias veran soy muy nuevo en esto y recientemente me encargaron la tarea de mandar correos. Tengo que crear un formulario que permita tomar recados y despues otro que sea para mandar notificaciones el de racados ya lo hice me permite guardar y modificar lo que esta escrito en la bd, pero el de notificaciones me pidieron que se le notificara a la persona por medio de un correo electronco automatico y en ese correo aparezaca el motivo y el mensaje usando phpmailer y la verdad no tengo ni la mas minima idea de como hacerlo ya trate pero no logro entenderlo no se si podrian ayudarme:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uhXZqRLhyszDTNMeABGqE2VYvwH8G4WX

En esa carpeta se encuentran todos los archivos que estoy usando para recado junto con una imagen de la bd cabe aclarar que se estan usando varias herramientas(jsgrid y bootstrap) usando js de igual forma, necesito ayuda por favor como lograria que funcione?

Comment: Genesis, generalmente es se hace en el controlador de tu eleccion. Si pudieras poner el codigo del controlador en donde lo estas intentando hacer seria bueno. Por lo menos yo (no estoy diciendo que sea algo general, solo yo) no visito links externos.

Comment: es que como es mucho codigo por eso lo puse asi queria ponerlo todo pero el mensaje queda demasiado largo

Comment: Genesis, voy a publicar una respuesta y espero que  pueda responder tu pregunta que, aunque creo que es un poco amplia, creo que aun es valida dentro del sitio.

Answer (score 3):

Hola puedes intentar lo siguiente:

1.- Puedes ejecutar una función cada ves que necesites enviar una notificación por email

2.- Para mandar email sencillo usando php mailer

 a) Descarga php mailer y descomprime la carpeta en "**tuproyecto**/application/libraries/"

 b) Carga librería de php mailer en function __construct() {} de tu controller

`require_once('application/libraries/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');`

 c) Usa php mailer en donde lo necesites

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
        $mail->Host = "Host";
        $mail->Port = 465;
        $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
        $mail->Username ='user@mail.com'; //Email para enviar
        $mail->Password = '123'; //Su password
        //Agregar destinatario
        $mail->setFrom('user@mail.com', 'user name sender');
        $mail->AddAddress('cliente@mail.com');//A quien mandar email
        $mail->Subject = "Notificación";
        $mail->msgHTML ("<h1>Ejemplo contenido html</h1>");
       if(!$mail->send()) {
      echo 'Error al enviar email';
      echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
     } else {
       echo 'Mail enviado correctamente';
     }
```

Comment: Tengo una duda en donde pones ** $mail->Username ='user@mail.com'; //Email para enviar** y **$mail->Password = '123'; //Su password** A QUE CUENTA SE REFIERE ?

Comment: Me refiero a la cuenta existente que vas a usar como servidor SMTP o servidor de envío

Comment: si no estoy equivocado en esta parte **$mail->Host = "Host";** que tengo que pones para envias atraves de Gmail

Comment: smtp.gmail.com, también debes usar el puerto 465 para SSL(recomendado) o 587 para TLS

Answer (score 0):

En CodeIgniter existe la libreria `email` para enviar correos electronicos.

En la teoria, los controladores deben ser los que manejan todas estas acciones, asi que en uno de tu eleccion, puedes tener una funcion parecida a la siguiente:

```
public function enviarcorreo(){

  $correo = $this->input->post('email');

  $this->load->library('email');

  $config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
  $config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
  $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
  $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

  $this->email->initialize($config);

  $this->email->from('info@tucompania.com', 'Nombre de tu compania');
  $this->email->to($correo);

  $this->email->subject('Email');
  $this->email->message('Aqui iria el mensaje que necesitas enviar."]);

  $this->email->send();
}
```

En este caso hipotético y simplificado, este es el paso de las acciones

1. Recibimos el correo electrónico del destinatario por medio de una petición post (esto sería algo común, pero puede ser que este almacenado en la base de datos)
2. Cargamos la libreria email
3. Se usa la configuración por defecto
4. Se inicializa la configuración
5. Especificamos el remitente y destinatario
6. Especificamos el titulo y el contenido
7. La función `send()` manda el mensaje

---

Entiendo que no es `phpmailer`, pero si estas usando CodeIgniter, ten en cuenta que ya existe una libreria para esto y no es necesario usar otra mas, sino, para que estas usando el framework?